# Is it possible to disassemble html?

Tags: javascript, html

For testing purpose I create simple html with one button. When you click on button it show you  alert. I try to to change button text value with olly, ida, and cheatengine to some other value but it doesn't work. Why?

Is it possible to change value of variable of html, is it possible to disassemble program like iexplorer?

Simple html on what i worked look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction()
{
alert("I am an alert box!");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Show alert box" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think any of us understand what you are trying to achieve. Can you edit your question to be more specific, then hopefully we can help.

Comment: @RichardEv I told already your answer help me i will try with firebug get some information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Internet Explorer 9, hit *F12* to enable the [developer tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg589507%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This will show you the structure of your HTML, which you can then change. These will also allow you (via the *Script* tab) to set breakpoints and debug your JavaScript. From here you can change variable values.

For older versions of IE, similar functionality (though not including JavaScript debugging) is available in the [Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18359).

If you're using FireFox, try [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/).

If you're using Google Chrome, hit *F12* to display the developer tools.

Your terminology isn't correct by the way: HTML does not get compiled (or assembled), so the idea of disassembling it isn't valid. The word you're probably looking for is *debug*.

Comment: Newer version of Firefox have developer tools build in as well. Besides, I think Chrome's developer tools are the best right now so they should be mentioned too.

Comment: Unless I'm using it wrong, Chrome's dev tools are terrible for editing HTML. Firebug is much better.

Comment: ... thnx for replay but my question is asked as well, i didn't say that want to change value in design ... i want change value from memory adres from computer, that is why i used ida, olly, etc

Comment: @tonni - In that case I/we have not understood your question. Can you edit it to include more detail please.

Comment: It appears that the question is not really about HTML/CSS but more about application hacking and disassembly. Maybe the tags, not the question should be changed to reflect this.

Comment: @RichardEv One more time thnx for answere, the question is specific and more for people who have much experiences in debugging and reversing, the real answer will be vary complicated , .... let stay your answare ... thnx on more time...

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Internet Explorer, don't hit F12 to enable the developer tools. This will only show you the structure of your HTML badly, which you can then change with difficulty.

Instead, make sure you're using FireFox, and then install the extension [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) which will enable you to view and edit HTML/CSS and Javascript live in the browser (and much more).

Comment: IME the IE developer tools do a great job of showing you the structure of your HTML.

Comment: @RichardEv `great` compared to what? If someone was starting up in developing websites, would you recommend IE over Firefox as the development environment of preference? I would not - I would prefer to give new programmers a head start into discovering a set of tools that make development a pleasure to use. Turns out however, that the OP is not talking about the HTML at all.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean you want?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function olly()
{
alert("Olly");
}

function cheatengine()
{
alert("cheatengine");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" onclick="olly()" value="olly" />
<input type="button" onclick="cheatengine()" value="cheatengine" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thnx for effort but no ... i search for disassemble firefox which have inside code of html which i show in example